# What are the rules for HTML attribute values?

Tags: html

When declaring an attribute value such as `id="attributeValue"` are there any particular rules on what characters are/aren't allowed?

I have always assumed that the first letter must always be a letter (a-z or A-Z) followed by pretty much any character(s). Then I realised this is the rules for declaring PHP variables

So what are the rules for declaring an attribute, and are they the same for all attributes e.g. `id`, `name`, `href`, `type` etc

Comment: It depends greatly on `doctype`... any particular one?

Comment: Check out the [Attributes index](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/section-index.html#attributes-1) of the HTML standard. The expected values are defined in the "Value" column.

Comment: Or check this section (HTML 4.01 spec): http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-cdata

Comment: So, for example, the rules for the `id` attribute are: At least one character and no space characters.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Only for HTML5. Otherwise, the rules are "must begin with a letter, and be followed by any number of letters, digits, hyphens, underscores, colons and periods."

Comment: @James There is no "HTML5" anymore - it's now called [HTML Living Standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/). This standard supersedes the HTML 4 standard.

Comment: @Šime - I know what you mean, but many people are still using older `doctype`s, in which case the old rules will still apply.

Comment: @James I doubt that. From my understanding, the *only* purpose of the DOCTYPE is to trigger standards mode. And in standards mode, the browsers apply the *same* rules regardless of the DOCTYPE. So you can have a "HTML 4 DOCTYPE", or just `<!doctype html>` - the browser doesn't care.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Yes, but if you don't say "HTML5", very few know what you mean. ;)

Comment: @Guffa That's why the WHATWG renamed it into "HTML Living Standard" in the first place - to make it clear that this is one language - HTML - which continuously evolves. From now on, it's just HTML, and if people don't understand what happened to HTML5... well, then somebody should tell them `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#h-6.2

So, your assumptions is pretty good, but "followed by pretty much any characters" is a bit optimistic.